Print list (or tree) of active TRY blocks
I am debugging some complicated legacy Python3 code and find myself needing to know, at a particular point in the executing code, all the try blocks that are active in the call stack.  Is there a way to introspect and print out the nested tree?
So, for example, we might have this code:
def fn1():
    try:
        fn2()
    except IOError:
        # do something

def fn2():
    try:
        fn3()
    except NameError:
        # do something

def fn3():
    print( **YourAnswerHere** )

The idea is that if I invoke fn1() then the print statement in fn3 would produce something like:
    fn1: try / except IOError
        fn2: try / except NameError

If that's not possible, I'd be able to get along if it merely printed [fn1 fn2].  Ideally it would handle try / finally blocks as well.
I could find nothing about this using Google.  I looked at every occurrence of the word try in the documentation for Python's inspect and traceback modules but found nothing.  The ast module has classes related to try but I don't have a clue how to use them and it looks like those are for analyzing static code, rather than executing code.  Thank you.

Do the answers to this question help at all?

It would! ... But, it seems critical that it was written for Python3.7.  I tested the top-rated answer's code in 3.9 and 3.11 and the second print statement produces None.

What about traceback? https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html Oh, you mean even if there was no exception?

@Kenny Ostrom: Righto -- even if there is no exception raised.

You can use inspect and dis modules for inspection:
import inspect, dis


def _active():
    res = []
    for f in inspect.stack()[1:]:
        res.extend(_blocks(f.frame.f_code))
    return res


def _blocks(code):
    res = []
    for i in dis.get_instructions(code):
        if i.opcode == dis.opmap['SETUP_EXCEPT']:
            res.append((code.co_name, "try"))
        elif i.opcode == dis.opmap['SETUP_FINALLY']:
            res.append((code.co_name, "finally"))
    return res


def fn1():
    try:
        fn2()
    except IOError:
        print("fn2 IOError")
    finally:
        print("fn1 Done")


def fn2():
    try:
        fn3()
    except NameError:
        print("fn2 NameError")
    finally:
        print("fn2 Done")


def fn3():
    print(_active())


fn1()


Prints
[('fn2', 'finally'), ('fn2', 'try'), ('fn1', 'finally'), ('fn1', 'try')]
fn2 Done
fn1 Done


You can also define a global level and generate a tree:
import inspect, dis

level = 0


def _active():
    res = []
    for f in inspect.stack()[1:]:
        res.extend(_blocks(f.frame.f_code))
    return res


def _blocks(code):
    global level
    res = []
    for i in dis.get_instructions(code):
        if i.opcode == dis.opmap['SETUP_EXCEPT']:
            res.append(("\t" * level + code.co_name, "try"))
            level += 1
        elif i.opcode == dis.opmap['SETUP_FINALLY']:
            res.append(("\t" * level + code.co_name, "finally"))
            level += 1
    return res


def fn1():
    global level
    try:
        indent = level * "\t"
        fn2()
    except IOError:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn1 IOError")
    finally:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn1 Done")
    level -= 1


def fn2():
    global level
    try:
        indent = level * "\t"
        fn3()
    except NameError:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn2 NameError")
    finally:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn2 Done")
    level -= 1


def fn3():
    global level
    try:
        indent = level * "\t"
        fn4()
    except NameError:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn3 NameError")
    finally:
        indent = level * "\t"
        print(f"{indent} fn3 Done")
    level -= 1


def fn4():
    _tree(_active())


def _tree(blocks):
    for b, t in blocks:
        print(f"{b}: {t}")


fn1()



Prints
fn3: finally
    fn3: try
        fn2: finally
            fn2: try
                fn1: finally
                    fn1: try
                         fn3 Done
                     fn2 Done
                 fn1 Done


Details

See dis — Disassembler for Python bytecode

{
    'POP_TOP': 1,
    'ROT_TWO': 2,
    'ROT_THREE': 3,
    'DUP_TOP': 4,
    'DUP_TOP_TWO': 5,
    'NOP': 9,
    'UNARY_POSITIVE': 10,
    'UNARY_NEGATIVE': 11,
    'UNARY_NOT': 12,
    'UNARY_INVERT': 15,
    'BINARY_MATRIX_MULTIPLY': 16,
    'INPLACE_MATRIX_MULTIPLY': 17,
    'BINARY_POWER': 19,
    'BINARY_MULTIPLY': 20,
    'BINARY_MODULO': 22,
    'BINARY_ADD': 23,
    'BINARY_SUBTRACT': 24,
    'BINARY_SUBSCR': 25,
    'BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE': 26,
    'BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE': 27,
    'INPLACE_FLOOR_DIVIDE': 28,
    'INPLACE_TRUE_DIVIDE': 29,
    'GET_AITER': 50,
    'GET_ANEXT': 51,
    'BEFORE_ASYNC_WITH': 52,
    'BEGIN_FINALLY': 53,
    'END_ASYNC_FOR': 54,
    'INPLACE_ADD': 55,
    'INPLACE_SUBTRACT': 56,
    'INPLACE_MULTIPLY': 57,
    'INPLACE_MODULO': 59,
    'STORE_SUBSCR': 60,
    'DELETE_SUBSCR': 61,
    'BINARY_LSHIFT': 62,
    'BINARY_RSHIFT': 63,
    'BINARY_AND': 64,
    'BINARY_XOR': 65,
    'BINARY_OR': 66,
    'INPLACE_POWER': 67,
    'GET_ITER': 68,
    'GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER': 69,
    'PRINT_EXPR': 70,
    'LOAD_BUILD_CLASS': 71,
    'YIELD_FROM': 72,
    'GET_AWAITABLE': 73,
    'INPLACE_LSHIFT': 75,
    'INPLACE_RSHIFT': 76,
    'INPLACE_AND': 77,
    'INPLACE_XOR': 78,
    'INPLACE_OR': 79,
    'BREAK_LOOP': 80,
    'WITH_CLEANUP_START': 81,
    'WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH': 82,
    'RETURN_VALUE': 83,
    'IMPORT_STAR': 84,
    'SETUP_ANNOTATIONS': 85,
    'YIELD_VALUE': 86,
    'POP_BLOCK': 87,
    'END_FINALLY': 88,
    'POP_EXCEPT': 89,
    'STORE_NAME': 90,
    'DELETE_NAME': 91,
    'UNPACK_SEQUENCE': 92,
    'FOR_ITER': 93,
    'UNPACK_EX': 94,
    'STORE_ATTR': 95,
    'DELETE_ATTR': 96,
    'STORE_GLOBAL': 97,
    'DELETE_GLOBAL': 98,
    'LOAD_CONST': 100,
    'LOAD_NAME': 101,
    'BUILD_TUPLE': 102,
    'BUILD_LIST': 103,
    'BUILD_SET': 104,
    'BUILD_MAP': 105,
    'LOAD_ATTR': 106,
    'COMPARE_OP': 107,
    'IMPORT_NAME': 108,
    'IMPORT_FROM': 109,
    'JUMP_FORWARD': 110,
    'JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP': 111,
    'JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP': 112,
    'JUMP_ABSOLUTE': 113,
    'POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE': 114,
    'POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE': 115,
    'LOAD_GLOBAL': 116,
    'CONTINUE_LOOP': 119,
    'SETUP_LOOP': 120,
    'SETUP_EXCEPT': 121,
    'SETUP_FINALLY': 122,
    'LOAD_FAST': 124,
    'STORE_FAST': 125,
    'DELETE_FAST': 126,
    'RAISE_VARARGS': 130,
    'CALL_FUNCTION': 131,
    'MAKE_FUNCTION': 132,
    'BUILD_SLICE': 133,
    'MAKE_CLOSURE': 134,
    'LOAD_CLOSURE': 135,
    'LOAD_DEREF': 136,
    'STORE_DEREF': 137,
    'DELETE_DEREF': 138,
    'CALL_FUNCTION_KW': 141,
    'CALL_FUNCTION_EX': 142,
    'SETUP_WITH': 143,
    'EXTENDED_ARG': 144,
    'LIST_APPEND': 145,
    'SET_ADD': 146,
    'MAP_ADD': 147,
    'LOAD_CLASSDEREF': 148,
    'BUILD_LIST_UNPACK': 149,
    'BUILD_MAP_UNPACK': 150,
    'BUILD_MAP_UNPACK_WITH_CALL': 151,
    'BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK': 152,
    'BUILD_SET_UNPACK': 153,
    'SETUP_ASYNC_WITH': 154,
    'FORMAT_VALUE': 155,
    'BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP': 156,
    'BUILD_STRING': 157,
    'BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK_WITH_CALL': 158,
}


On my machine this produces no output at all.  Putting a print statement as the first statement in the for loop in _blocks discloses that the first block has an opname of "RESUME" and that is the only block.

Appreciate the updates.  On my M1 Mac, the top implementation works in Python 3.9.10 and 3.9.18.  However, on 3.11.6 it still falls short, outputting only [].  Of course, my application is using 3.11.6.  :-).

Changing to POP_BLOCK still generates [], however, changing to POP_EXCEPT is an improvement: the output on Python 3.11 becomes: [('fn2', 'try'), ('fn2', 'try'), ('fn2', 'try'), ('fn1', 'try'), ('fn1', 'try'), ('fn1', 'try')].  I can work with this, but will leave the question open for a little bit, to see if anything else turns up.  Thanks!
